# Drawing an Arc in PPTX

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I want to draw an arc using Apache POI. For that, it is quite unclear which API I need to set the points used for drawing.

```
protected void draw(final XMLSlideShow ppt, final XSLFGroupShape containerGroupShape) {
    final XSLFFreeformShape shape = containerGroupShape.createFreeform();

    // Positioning
    double x = container.toPptX(pos.getX());
    double y = container.toPptY(pos.getY());
    double w = container.toPpt(pos.getW());
    double h = container.toPpt(pos.getH());

    // Set shape type & anchor
    shape.setShapeType(ShapeType.ARC);
    shape.setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h));

    shape.setFillColor(toAwtColor(fillColor));
    shape.setLineColor(toAwtColor(strokeColor));

    // Which API do I need here?
    Path2D.Double gp = new Path2D.Double();
    gp.moveTo(0, 0);
    gp.lineTo(10, 10);
    gp.closePath();
    shape.setPath(gp);
}
```

(Note: this is the method responsible to create arcs in the pptx file)

I know that Polygons uses `Path2D.Double`, but that kind of does not work (or my example data is wrong?). I even tried looking into the VCS repo, but I had no luck finding any testcase using the arc shape

Does somebody know how the arc data (start angle, arc length) is configured?

Edit:

To avoid future confusion:

- I don't know how to describe the curve. I am not **just** describing a curve via 2 points.
- The code above is an example I am testing with and does **not** work

Comment: I believe **either** you can create [XSLFSimpleShape](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSimpleShape.html) of type `ShapeType.ARC`. There the arc is a quarter circle in the rectangle described by the anchor, maybe rotated. **Or** you create a free form shape using a path. But you can't do both in combination.

Comment: Sadly, that does not help. XSLFSimpleShape is package-private and cannot be instantiated. Also, I am already drawing polygons and rectangulars using a similiar algorithm as above. The problem I am facing at this moment is that the CustomGeometry from the FreeFormShape is null while setPath is called. And the quarter circle arc is no option, since I need control over the length of the arc and by that, control over the angle.

Comment: `XSLFFreeformShape` as well as `XSLFAutoShape` extend `XSLFSimpleShape` and thus inherit it's methods. As said free form shape should be possible too. But a path of only two single points is a little bit scant for describing an arc, isn't it? Will providing an example this evening (evening in Germany ;-)) if nobody else has answered.

Comment: @AxelRichter I added some facts to the question so you won't make false assumptions again :) I will experiment with the API while waiting for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said **either** you can create [XSLFSimpleShape](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSimpleShape.html) of type `ShapeType.ARC`. There the default arc is a quarter circle in the rectangle described by the anchor. **Or** you create a free form shape using a path. But you can't do both in combination.

If you create a default `ShapeType.ARC` and look at this in `PowerPoint` you will see two handles for setting start and end angle. Do manipulating them and then save the file and then simply unzip the `*.pptx` file and have a look at `/ppt/slides/slide1.xml`. There you will find

```
<a:avLst>
 <a:gd name="adj1" fmla="val [startAngle]"/>
 <a:gd name="adj2" fmla="val [endAngle]"/>
</a:avLst>
```

So we need the `AvLst` which is a `CTGeomGuideList` and then we can manipulate the two handles (adjustments) programmatically.

The only thing we must know additionally is what are the possible values for start angle and end angle. Some test settings leads to the insight that the 0 point is on 3 o'clock position and a full circle is 21,600,000. So 6 o'clock position is 5,400,000, 9 o'clock position is 10,800,000, 12 o'clock position is 16,200,000. Those values are independent of the size of  the whole circle and are even correct if the rectangle is not a square and so the arcs are elliptic.

The following code shows how to draw arcs using that `ShapeType.ARC`.

It also shows how to use `XSLFFreeformShape` for drawing arcs. The simplest way here is drawing a Bézier arc because [java.awt.geom.Path2D.Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html) already provides a method for creating Bézier paths.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.CTShape;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTGeomGuideList;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTGeomGuide;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D.Double;

public class CreatePPTXArcShape {

 private static XSLFAutoShape createArcShape(XSLFSlide slide, Rectangle positionAndSize, 
  int startAngle, int endAngle, Color color) {

  XSLFAutoShape arcShape = ((XSLFSlide)slide).createAutoShape();
  arcShape.setShapeType(ShapeType.ARC);
  arcShape.setLineColor(color);
  arcShape.setAnchor(positionAndSize);

  startAngle = startAngle % 360;
  endAngle = endAngle % 360;

  XmlObject xmlObject = arcShape.getXmlObject();
  CTShape ctShape = (CTShape)xmlObject;
  CTGeomGuideList ctGeomGuideList = ctShape.getSpPr().getPrstGeom().getAvLst();
  CTGeomGuide ctGeomGuide = ctGeomGuideList.addNewGd();
  ctGeomGuide.setName("adj1");
  ctGeomGuide.setFmla("val " + (21600000/360*startAngle));
  ctGeomGuide = ctGeomGuideList.addNewGd();
  ctGeomGuide.setName("adj2");
  ctGeomGuide.setFmla("val " + (21600000/360*endAngle));

  return arcShape;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  SlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

  Slide slide = slideShow.createSlide();

  XSLFAutoShape arcShape;

  //circle arcs
  arcShape = createArcShape((XSLFSlide)slide, new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100), 
   0, 90, Color.BLUE); //0 degrees = 3 o'clock position, 90 degrees = 6 o'clock position, 
  arcShape = createArcShape((XSLFSlide)slide, new Rectangle(150, 100, 100, 100), 
   180, 0, Color.BLUE); //180 degrees = 9 o'clock position
  arcShape = createArcShape((XSLFSlide)slide, new Rectangle(200, 100, 100, 100), 
   270, 90, Color.BLUE); //270 degrees = 12 o'clock position
  arcShape = createArcShape((XSLFSlide)slide, new Rectangle(300, 100, 100, 100), 
   180+45, 270+45, Color.BLUE); 
  arcShape = createArcShape((XSLFSlide)slide, new Rectangle(400, 100, 100, 100), 
   0, 359, Color.BLUE); 

  //elliptic arcs
  arcShape = createArcShape((XSLFSlide)slide, new Rectangle(100, 250, 100, 50), 
   0, 90, Color.BLUE); 
  arcShape = createArcShape((XSLFSlide)slide, new Rectangle(150, 250, 100, 50), 
   180, 0, Color.BLUE); 
  arcShape = createArcShape((XSLFSlide)slide, new Rectangle(200, 250, 100, 50), 
   270, 90, Color.BLUE); 
  arcShape = createArcShape((XSLFSlide)slide, new Rectangle(300, 250, 100, 50), 
   180+45, 270+45, Color.BLUE); 
  arcShape = createArcShape((XSLFSlide)slide, new Rectangle(400, 250, 100, 50), 
   0, 359, Color.BLUE); 

  //Bézier freeform arcs
  XSLFFreeformShape bezierShape = ((XSLFSlide)slide).createFreeform();
  bezierShape.setLineColor(Color.BLUE);
  Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
  path.moveTo(100d, 400d); // x = 100px from left of slide, y = 400px from top of slide
  path.curveTo(100d, 400d, 150d, 600d, 200d, 400d); // y of middle point is greater than y of baseline => arc downwards
  bezierShape.setPath(path);

  bezierShape = ((XSLFSlide)slide).createFreeform();
  bezierShape.setLineColor(Color.BLUE);
  path = new Path2D.Double();
  path.moveTo(300d, 400d);
  path.curveTo(300d, 400d, 350d, 200d, 400d, 400d); // y of middle point is less than y of baseline => arc upwards
  bezierShape.setPath(path);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreatePPTXArcShape.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: I lost track abit of the topic while working on something else. Your answer is great! Thing that wasn't clear before is the fact that there is no API to set the handles directly, but to manipulate the underlying xml object. Thank you very much, sir!